# How can I solve this number grid?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I'm trying to get the values of A,B,C,D,E and F. I thought at first it might be Sudoku but the grid seems too large.

Here is the hint I've been given.

> Rightly to begin to solve the Logic Box puzzle you must ask what determines the positions of 7 and 5 in row two
>
> **FYI** the colour of the cells within the logic box are of no relevance

[image: The Puzzle]

Comment: why did they have to use three shades of blue?

Comment: @Jasen I forgot to put in that they specifically say the colour have no relevance. Updating question now...

Comment: Thanks for wanting to participate on Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**) Note that we generally don't accept questions from ongoing tests, competitions or contests, and we definitely don't accept plagiarised content - you need to provide at minimum an attribution about where the content came from if it is not your own (and any additional context you can provide is usually a big help). Please provide attribution, as posts consisting of plagiarised content are deleted.

Comment: @Rubio Please note that plagiarism means passing someone else's work off as your own, which this puzzle is **definitely not doing**. Not citing their exact source isn't the same as saying they made it themselves.

Comment: @Rubio thanks for letting me know the rules of this site. I appreciate that, however I would like to reiterate what Rand said that this is not plagerised in anyway. I thought this was clear. The puzzle was from the geocaching website (not a competition), next time I shall publish the link with it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I didn't mean to suggest that you had claimed the puzzle content as your own (clearly you did not), but rather that you were using someone else's content without attribution. Apologies for the overly broad language in my comment, which is text I use when the source should be given but wasn't. I'll try to word that better in the future. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer:

> \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}\text{A}=2&\text{B}=7&\text{C}=3&\text{D}=8&\text{E}=6&\text{F}=9\end{array}

Explanation:

> The numbers are always in the position determined by the number following them in the previous row.
>
> Since 7 is followed by 3 in the first row, it is in the third position on the second row and 5 is followed by 8 on the first row so it is in the eighth position on the second row.
>
> The full grid looks like this:
> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline1&9&7&3&4&6&2&5&8\\\hline8&6&7&3&2&4&9&5&1\\\hline5&3&7&2&9&8&6&1&4\\\hline6&7&5&1&4&8&3&9&2\\\hline5&9&8&1&7&2&6&4&3\\\hline8&7&4&6&3&2&1&9&5\\\hline2&3&6&7&9&4&8&5&1\\\hline5&1&2&9&8&3&6&4&7\\\hline5&1&8&6&7&3&4&9&2\\\hline5&9&7&3&2&8&6&1&4\\\hline6&3&7&1&4&8&9&2&5\\\hline7&9&6&1&2&5&3&4&8\\\hline6&1&5&3&2&9&8&4&7\\\hline\end{array}